# How to disable parent term options in select list?

Tags: 7, forms, views

I have a view with an exposed filter of taxonomy terms. The terms are displayed as a hierarchical structure in the select list. I want to disable the parent terms in the select list. How to do it in Drupal way?

Comment: How would you do that using standard HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question.

Comment: In an HTML select list, how do you disable options? I wasn't aware that you could and Drupal doesn't affect how HTML works. You'll need to come up with a way to do that in HTML before working out how to apply it to Drupal

Comment: @Clive is right, though I suppose you could use [optgroups](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) instead

Comment: I do not know much about optgroups. Does it integrate with views module?

Comment: `The HTML <optgroup> element creates a grouping of options within a <select> element.` So they can be used everywhere a select can be used. How to get them in views is a different question. You could try this patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/1695658

Comment: @Neograph734 Thank you very much! The patch works like charm and it provides expected output i.e. user cannot select parent term and hence it is as good as disabled. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to disable the parent term in the select list (views exposed filter) so that the user is not able to select it. This is how I achieved the desired functionality -

As mentioned by @Neograph734, using `<optgroup>` creates a grouping of options within `<select>` element. I applied the patch at drupal.org/node/1695658 that @Neograph734 provided.

Then in the views filter section, I selected the desired taxonomy reference field. Selected options as shown below - 
[image]
Configured the field as an exposed filter. As as result you can see it as per below - 
[image]

Now the user can select only child terms and not the parent terms.